# How to identify system is up?

Tags: linux, unix

Once the system is shutdown there will be message in syslog file. I have identified that message in syslog file. But I need to identify the appropriate message for system up status. Please explain me the way to identify that message in syslog file.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe if the last line is *not* a shutdown message?

Comment: If you can do something on the machine, it's up. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I am asking any way to identify the system up status in syslog file itself?

Comment: 1. How do you define 'system up'? 'system up' can mean different things to different people. 2. Why are you trying to do this? i.e. why are you trying to read syslog to find 'system up' status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always look for the running of anacron jobs. These jobs are run when the time of the cron job has passed and was not executed. Once the System is up, It will run anacron jobs asap.
And also, I dont think the last line in the syslog is shutdown message always.

**Job `cron.weekly' started** will be in the anacron if the com is up ...